# Maintain exponential number in javascript property

Tags: javascript

The user can enter an exponential value such as 1.5e+3 in an input field. I want to store the value exactly as the user entered it into a Javascript object but not as a string. I then want to convert this object to JSON and maintain the format as the user entered it. Is this possible? Currently, if I use Number("1.5e+3"), it converts this to a decimal number.

In JSON, you can set a property to an exponential value without the value being in quotation marks:

```
{
   "someNumber": 1.5e-3
}
```

Comment: With the build in `JSON.stringify` you don’t have control over how the number is represented in the output.

Comment: If the input format is standardized (`number e+ exp` or `number e- exp`), then you can obtain it from the input as a string, split it on the "e" (or maybe use regex to support "e" and "E"), and then parse and store each part separately. E.g., like this: `"1.5e+3".split(/[eE]/)` (returns an array of strings `["1.5", "+3"]`). Or you can change the UI to have two input fields.

Comment: "*I want to store the value exactly as the user entered it into a Javascript object but not as a string*" why "not a string"? That's the only way to keep formatted data. The only alternative is a complex object `{ base: 1.5, exponent: -3}`

Comment: @VLAZ Because in JSON, exponential numbers are not stored as strings.

Comment: @AndroidDev that's the thing - you *cannot* mandate a specific format on numbers. The only way to do it is to record them as strings. You'd then need to read them back from a string, of course, but it's usually much easier than mostly anything else.

Comment: Everything in JSON is a string. There's a difference between JavaScript objects and JSON.

Comment: @AndroidDev in JSON there is only one type for numbers which is a floating type number. Which can be represented in the `e` format, but it’s not a distinct type.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović No, JSON has the value types boolean, string, number, array, object, and null. JSON is a string-based interchange format, but it has types.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović No, everything in JSON is not a string. Numbers and booleans (true/false) do not have quotation marks around them. While JSON as a whole may be considered a string, the actual properties are treated by data types.

Comment: @t.niese - OK, maybe I was a bit too nitpicky, but JSON is a serialization format, and everything is technically text; there are conventions that enable JavaScript to parse it as those types when it reads it. I was responding to AndroidDev's remark that "exponential numbers are not stored as strings".

Comment: @FilipMilovanović A JavaScript file is technically also text and parsed. It is highly misleading to say everything in JSON is a string. Because clearly in JSON `1` is a number, `true` is a boolean, `"1"` is a string, … and defined by the specification of JSON.

Comment: @AndroidDev - OK, I agree with that; the point is, they are read in as text and then *parsed* as those data types. The parser reads a text in exponential notation as a floating point number - if you want to keep the exponent as it was entered, you have to store it separately.

Comment: @AndroidDev - one more question; just to clarify what you're asking for. Suppose you are able to store it in JSON the way you want, as `"someNumber": 1.5e-3`. When this is read back in by your application or another application as a JavaScript object, it's going to convert it to a decimal number just like `Number("1.5e+3")` - is that of concern or not? (I.e., are you just interested in preserving the exponential notation in the output, or do you need to preserve it beyond that?)